# notification ever day xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I want to create an alert on every day at the same time.

Sample code is below :

```
- (IBAction)start:(id)sender {

    [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"notificationIsActive"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    self.message.text=@"Напоминание включено";


    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay) fromDate:date];
    components.calendar = calendar;
    components.hour = 7;
    components.minute = 37;
    date = components.date;

    if([date compare:[NSDate date]] < 0) {
        date = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24];
    }

    UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    localNotification.alertBody = @"ТЕКСТ НАПОМИНАНИЯ";
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitDay;//NSCalendarUnitMinute; //Repeating instructions here.
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Local Notification "Everyday at 7:00am" not notifying](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13296190/local-notification-everyday-at-700am-not-notifying)

Comment: refer to this ans http://stackoverflow.com/a/23748277/4003548.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date]; 
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotif.fireDate = date;
localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotif.repeatInterval=NSCalendarUnitDay;
localNotif.alertBody = @"Daily Notification"; 

localNotif.userInfo=@{
                     };
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
```