# how to fire random local notification at same time everyday in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am working on a app which required local notifications. I have an array of text with multiple objects and i need to fire every elements of array each day. 
I am facing a lot of problem in this. Every time only one notification should be fired from an array.
Help me on this.

UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

```
        notification.fireDate = fireDateOfNotification;
        notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
        NSString *myString = SelectedAffirmationText;
        NSArray *myArray = [myString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@","]];
        //NSString *StrForNotification=[myArray objectAtIndex:0];

        for(int i=0;i<myArray.count;i++)
        {
          NSString *StrForNotification=[myArray objectAtIndex:i];
         notification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",StrForNotification];
        }


        notification.alertAction = @"go back";
        NSDictionary *userDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:DateSelected, @"Date", TimeSelected, @"Time",SelectedAffirmationText,@"DataAffiramtion", nil];

        notification.userInfo = userDict;
        notification.repeatInterval= NSDayCalendarUnit;
        notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

Comment: add some codes you are working.

Comment: @Arun added the code..go through it and suggest the answer

Comment: Try this link this may help you [fire local notification per day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13296190/local-notification-everyday-at-700am-not-notifying)

Comment: thanks for your answer but this is not the solution for which i m looking for. my every day repeatation of the notification is working fine but the text i am getting is same every time i need to change the text of the notification everytime

Comment: @RamanSrivastava have you got any idea? Am also stuck with same part.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 10.0 add time to your local notification as below. You have to add notification framework

```
var date = DateComponents()
date.hour = 22
let calendarTrigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: date, repeats: true)
```

Create a content as below

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = "Title"
content.subtitle = "Subtitle"
content.body = "Some  body."
content.badge = 1
content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
```

Now create UNNotificationRequest and pass content, trigger.

Currently, the UserNotifications framework provides three for you:

UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger, which allows a notification to be sent a set amount of time after scheduling it.

UNCalendarNotificationTrigger, which allows a notification to be sent at a specific date and time, regardless of when it was scheduled.

UNLocationNotificationTrigger, which allows a notification to be sent when the user enters or leaves a designated geographical region.